# Implementing ICollection.CopyTo in C#: deep or shallow copy?

Tags: c#, copy, clone, interface-implementation

I'm writing a custom class which implements `IDictionary`, and I'm not sure what to do about `CopyTo`. Should each element just be copied to the target array (shallow copy), or should I make a copy/clone of each element then place it in the target array (deep copy)?

Comment: Which `CopyTo` are you referring to? `IEnumerable` has no `CopyTo` method.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `ICollection` does though, and since OP is implementing an `IDictionary`, I suspect they need to implement `ICollection.CopyTo`.

Comment: I suspect the same, but we should demand precision, since computers do precisely what we tell them to do.

Comment: Ahhh, whoops! Sorry about that. I'll edit the question...

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionarybase.copyto.aspx. Better still, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645053.aspx

Comment: Also, are you really implementing `IDictionary` or the generic `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: @Asad Neither, actually: I'm implementing `IDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, MyClass>`. I figured the question applied regardless, though, so I left that detail out.

Comment: Always shallow for `IDictionary`. Since the elements are of type `object` you have no way of knowing how to do a deep copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is not defined by the contract, however all the generic collections appear to do a shallow copy (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=List.CopyTo). It makes sense, as there is no defined way to deep copy any `object`, which would be part of the `CopyTo` implementation.

It depends on your scenario, if you do not intend to use this method at all, consider not implementing it and throwing a `NotSupportedException`. If others will use your collection, implement a shallow copy to align with the standard .NET library. If you need a deep copy method, add it as a separate method, (potentially by implementing `ICloneable`).